# App does not display when searched with the app name on Android Market (Google Play)

Tags: android

My app on Android Market (Google Play) has a name, Motivational Quotes, but when I search for it with that name it does not show up. But when I search without a space (like Motivationalquotes) it shows up. How can I solve this? Because of this I will be losing many users.

When I tried searching on website using browser it only shows up when Motivationalquotes is searched. There is no keywords option in Android developers account to mention for searching the application (unlike Amazon or windows app stores).

Please help.

Comment: How old is your app ? Because referencing an app on Google Play is not immediate. You should also think about having this text in your description and/or title, and have web links with those words to your app on Internet.

Comment: My app is week old @gahfy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to wait a littel bit
 but you also can write in the description the app name
and when user will search it will find through the description